Reduce a string up to idempotency
Objective
Given a string consisting of printable ASCII characters (!0x21 ― ~0x7E), treat it as an element in the free idempotent monoid (as defined below) over the printable ASCII characters, and output the same element represented in the fewest characters as possible.
Free idempotent monoid
Recall that the free monoid over a set is essentially the collection of lists over the set, endowed with concatenation.
The free idempotent monoid is the quotient object of the free monoid that identifies the lists up to idempotency. In lay terms, if the list has two or more contiguous sub-lists that compare equal, the sub-lists can be replaced by one sub-list, while retaining overall equivalence of the list.
Proof of uniqueness
We want to show that, for two strings \$x\$ and \$y\$ that belong to the same equivalence class, if \$x\$ and \$y\$ both have the fewest characters in the class, \$x\$ and \$y\$ actually are the same string.
It's obvious that \$x\$ and \$y\$ consist of the same set of characters. If \$x\$ and \$y\$ both have length zero, we are done. Otherwise, let \$\alpha\$ be the first character in \$x\$, and let \$\beta\$ be the first character in \$y\$. Since every member of the class \$x\$ belongs has \$\alpha\$ as the first character, and likewise for \$y\$ and \$\beta\$, it follows that \$\alpha = \beta\$.
If \$x\$ and \$y\$ both have length one, we are done. Otherwise, let \$\alpha'\$ be the second character in \$x\$, and let \$\beta'\$ be the second character in \$y\$. It's obvious that \$\alpha' \neq \alpha\$ and \$\beta' \neq \beta\$. Now, every member of the the class \$x\$ belongs has \$\alpha'\$ as the first character when the longest prefix consisting of \$\alpha\$ is stripped off, and likewise for \$y\$ and \$\beta'\$, it follows that \$\alpha' = \beta'\$.
If \$x\$ and \$y\$ both have length two, we are done. Otherwise, let \$\alpha''\$ be the third character in \$x\$, and let \$\beta''\$ be the third character in \$y\$. It's obvious that the strings \$\alpha \alpha' \alpha''\$ and \$\beta \beta' \beta''\$ are irreducible. Now, every member of the the class \$x\$ belongs has \$\alpha''\$ as the first character when the longest prefix being equivalent to the string \$\alpha\alpha'\$ is stripped off, and likewise for \$y\$ and \$\beta''\$, it follows that \$\alpha'' = \beta''\$.
The proof is recursive until exhausting all characters in \$x\$ and \$y\$.
Examples
Here, the strings are double-quoted.
Input -> Output

"" -> ""
"x" -> "x"
"xx" -> "x"
"xy" -> "xy"
"!!?" -> "!?"
"+/+/" -> "+/"
"1+1+1" -> "1+1"
"1+2+1" -> "1+2+1"
"~~~" -> "~"
"TheThem" -> "Them"
"thethem" -> "them"
"cOUgh" -> "cOUgh"
"XIXAXA" -> "XIXA"
"IXIXAXA" -> "IXA"
"Xx" -> "Xx"
"198034034" -> "198034"
"...!...!" -> ".!"
"...!...?" -> ".!.?"
"Ook!Ook?" -> "Ook!Ook?"
"<o><oo>" -> "<o>"

Worked example
For suppose the inputted string is QUAQUAUAL. The substring QUA contiguously appears twice, enabling the input to be reduced to QUAUAL. Then again, it has the substring UA contiguously appearing twice, enabling the input to be reduced to QUAL. Then, we identify there is no substring contiguously appearing multiple times, resulting in outputting QUAL.

None of the current test cases require recursion, i.e. all reduced substrings are already contained within the input. This fooled one of my solution attempts. Suggested test case: "<ooo><oo>" -> "<o>"

@Jitse I know this can come off as argumentative, but I truly am just genuinely curious: What's the difference here between <ooo><oo> and <o><oo>? It seems you can reduce both of them without any strings not in the input to begin with "<ooo><oo>" -> "<oo><oo>" -> "<oo>" -> "<o>". Is it that it has paths that do involve new strings?  How about <ooq><oqq>?

I wonder if every equivalence class has exactly one irreducible word.  Many of the answers seem to assume that.

@Nitrodon Please read the uniqueness proof.

This is a lot of fancy words to say 'delete duplicate substrings'

@WheatWizard I didn't think of that path and indeed, <ooo><oo> is not as good a test case as I thought. <ooq><oqq> is better because the last reduction is necessarily <oq><oq> -> <oq>, which is not a substring of the input.

Suggested: bananas -> banas because in none of the current examples both ends of the string are "inert".

Do we have proof that 'coalescing' equal substring in any order leads us to the optimal solution? Or, in other words, is there a risk of remaining blocked on a irreducible non-optimal string?

@DannyuNDos I read that proof, but the main claim in the inductive step is stated without any justification that I can see, and I can't quite convince myself of its truth even at length 3.

I found a counterexample to what all sixteen current answers assume: abcbabc is a squarefree word, but is it equivalent to the shorter word abc (since both can be reduced from ababcbabc).

By extending that construction, I think I can prove that vuv is always equivalent to v, provided that every symbol in u also appears in v.  I'm hoping that this will turn out to be the only reduction rule needed.

@Nitrodon thanks, your counterexample answers my question above (in the negative). By the way, in English (word list from github: dwyl/english-words) your "vuv with every u in v" conjectured general form applies to 'oidioid', 'patapat', 'trinitrin'

I'm voting to close this as unclear, even though the task is well specified, because the proof of completeness is misleading. If the proof and the false claims supported by it are removed I'd be happy to reopen it. I don't think it is necessary to provide a replacement algorithm since the task is specified, although that would be nice.

At this point with so many answers relying on greedily replacing doubled substrings, I think the challenge would be best edited to explicitly allow any sequence of shortening replacements until no further ones can be done.

I do not see anything wrong with the challenge or the proof of uniqueness. Both are perfectly clear. The only issue is that everyone who tried to answer it got it wrong, but not because of any deficiency in the problem or how it is worded. I think it would be a mistake to change this very interesting question into the relatively boring one that everyone mistakenly answered.

However, it would of course be helpful if the question highlighted the existence of examples like abcbabc. Perhaps it would also be nice to have a proof that the problem is decidable!

Here's a proof of uvu ~ u where every symbol in v appears in u: the case |v|=0 is trivial, and |v|=1 is precisely the abcbabc situation (where a and c are arbitrary words).  If |v| > 1, let v=xy.  Then uxyu ~ uxy[uxu] = [ux]y[ux]u ~ uxu ~ u.

Now, if every symbol of uvw appears in both u and w, then uvw ~ uwuvw ~ uw.  It turns out that uvw -> uw and uu -> u are the only reduction steps needed.  This is proven by showing that, if w has single-step reductions to both x and y, then x and y can be further reduced 0 or more times to become the same string.  (The proof of this last statement uses about 9-10 cases, so it is too long for a comment.)

I second what @xnor said--greedy replacement until squarefree is worth having as a challenge one way or another, so we may as well transplant the actual challenge-as-posed elsewhere.

R, 48 bytes
\(s){while(s!=(s=sub("(.+)\\1","\\1",s,,T)))0;s}

Attempt This Online!

BTW, it's weird that sub("(.+)\\1","\\1",s) works as expected when the match is at the beginning of the string, but when the match is in the middle, perl=T is required...

I don't know if it's possible (I couldn't see anything in a quick Google...), but can you save a byte using "(.+)\\K\\1" as the pattern and a 1-byte predefined variable (or something...) for the empty string/Nil for the replacement argument?

@DomHastings I don't know anything shorter than "" for empty string - nice idea though!

JavaScript (ES6), 43 bytes
-2 thanks to @l4m2
f=s=>s==(s=s.replace(/(.+)\1/,"$1"))?s:f(s)

Try it online!

43

05AB1E (legacy), 8 bytes
Δ.œ€ÔJéн

Try it online or verify all test cases.
Explanation:
Δ         # Loop until the result no longer changes:
 .œ       #  Get all partitions of the current string
          #  (which will use the implicit input-string in the first iteration)
   €      #  Map over each partition:
    Ô     #   Connected uniquify all parts in this partition
     J    #  Join each connected uniquified partition back together
      é   #  Sort these strings by length (shortest to longest)
       н  #  Pop and keep the first/shortest one
          # (after the loop, the result is output implicitly)

Uses the legacy version of 05AB1E instead of the latest version, since the connected uniquify builtin Ô will interpret stringified numbers as numbers instead of strings. E.g. with input 11.0+1+1e1, the legacy program correctly connected uniqifies ["1","1",".0","+1","+1","e1"] to ["1",".0","+1","e1"] → "1.0+1e1", whereas the new version of 05AB1E will connected uniquify ["1","1.0","+1","+1e1"] to ["1"] → "1", since it interprets them all as the same number (1): try it online.

Haskell + hgl, 26 bytes
yyc$sk$h_>~l2 aT(mY<xys)ʃ

Attempt This Online!
This uses the adapted rule from Nitrodon, which has not been proven correct, but at least has not been proven incorrect.
Explanation

yyc: Repeat a function until reaching a fixed point.
sk: Replace all matches of a parser with their results.
h_: Parse some string.
>~: Feed the result of that parse into a function to create a second parse.
mY<xys: Parse some number of characters from the input
aT: Ignore the result of that and give the result of ...
ʃ: Parse the input string and return it.

This finds occurrences of xyx where y is made up of a subset of the characters of x, and replaces them with x until a fixed point is reached. y can potentially be empty here.
Reflection
This is ok. I'm not too happy with it but I initially expected much worse. This really has more of a glue problem than anything else.

I could add l2 aT and l2 aK, they will probably be used again sometime.
I have (?*>) and (<*?) for aT<py and aK^.py and (+*>) and (<*+) for aT<so and aK^.so. I could use (**>) = aT<my and (<**) = aK^.py.

The above are minor fixes, but I think the thing that would really fix the glue problem is having a version of (>~) which just returns the result from the left-hand side instead of the right hand-side. So:
(<~) =
  f' $ fb < ap pM

In which case this could look like:
yyc$sk$h_<~(mY<xys)>~ʃ

Although this wouldn't make this answer shorter than implementing either of the above, this does seem like the solution lightest on the glue and an operation which has a large reuse potential
Old versions
Here are some old versions which use the incorrect algorithm given in the question and currently used by all the other answers:
Parser, 21 13 bytes
yyc$sk$h_>~ʃ

Attempt This Online!
Explanation

yyc: Repeat until reaching a fixed point.
sk: Apply a parser as many times as possible to substrings.
h_>~ʃ: Parse some string twice. This returns the parsed string only once.

No parser, 21 bytes
yyc$mBl<(he~<<gr)<<pt

Attempt This Online!
Explanation

yyc: Repeat until reaching a fixed point.
pt: Get all partitions.
gr: Group each partition into groups of contiguous equal elements.
he: Get the first element of each group.
mBl: Get the smallest result.

Reflection
Although I only have two versions of this answer I am splitting the reflection into three based on three potential solutions to this challenge.
Parser version
I am happy with the parser version. I was annoyed by the operator precedence between (~<) and (#|)/(++) in the original version of the answer, but I'm not sure it's actually wrong in general, and now it's no longer a problem.
In the interest in coming up with something to improve here:

Maybe yyc<sk could have a builtin? I think this idiom of "apply a parser repeatedly to substrings until reaching a fixed point" could come up again. I just really kind of don't like making more parser consumers.
Weird as it is, I think fb ʃ could have a builtin. This isn't the first time I've used it, you can also use it for things like palindrome checking. Although I don't think it's useful enough to justify a 2 byte name and with a 3 byte name it wouldn't even save anything here.

Regex version
I don't think I could reasonably do this with regex right now, since I haven't implemented back-referencing yet. This is just yet another push to do that.
Non-parser version
I am rather frustrated with trying to build a non-parser version here. There is a lot to improve on this front.

A contiguous nub function would be useful.
I would like an "unpairs" function that basically undoes what pA does.
sps finds all the splits into two pieces. But here I'd like all partitions into 3 pieces. It'd be good to have builtin which takes a number, \$n\$, and finds all the partitions into \$n\$ pieces, with presets for small numbers like 3. pST eL3 almost does what I want, but it returns a list which is a bit annoying. It's also inefficient and 7 bytes long.


Unfortunately, it turns out that xyx -> x isn't quite enough. (Run your code with abcbabcacba and its reverse.)  I commented on the OP with a set of reductions that should work instead.

Japt, 10 bytes
I didn't understand the spec at all so this is based on the worked example & test cases.
e"(.+)%1"Ï

Try it (includes all test cases)

@Downvoter, please have the courtesy to leave a comment.

QuadR ≡, 9 bytes
Blatant rip-off of l4m2's golf of Arnauld's JavaScript solution — go upvote!
(.+)\1
\1

Try it online!

Brachylog, 15 14 bytes
{c~c₂ᶠo∋~jᵗc}ˡ

Try it online!
I wouldn't be surprised if there's a better way to do this.
...But, I mostly just took Jitse's comment about requiring recursion as a challenge.
{           }ˡ    Left reduce by:
 c                Concatenate the new element to the accumulator,
  ~c₂             then partition that result into two possibly-empty slices,
     ᶠo∋          trying the partitions in lexicographic order.
        ~jᵗ       Un-double the last slice,
           c      and concatenate the slices back together.


What is this magic? :^0 I've never used ˡ before. Neat!

@DLosc Half the time, I only remember it exists because its right-to-left counterpart ʳ is unimplemented! In any case, I figured adding a character would trigger at most one reduction if the processed prefix is already squarefree.

Nekomata, 8 bytes
ʷ{JYᵗƶ¿j

Attempt This Online!
ʷ{JYᵗƶ¿j
ʷ{          Loop until failure:
  J             Nondeterministically split the input into parts
                e.g. "QUAQUAUAL" may become ["QUA", "QUA", "UA", "L"]
   Y            Run length encode
                e.g. ["QUA", "QUA", "UA", "L"] -> ["QUA", "UA", "L"], [2, 1, 1]
    ᵗƶ          Check that at least one count is greater than 1
                e.g. [2, 1, 1] passes
      ¿         If the check passes, drop the counts; otherwise fail
                e.g. ["QUA", "UA", "L"], [2, 1, 1] -> ["QUA", "UA", "L"]
       j        Join
                e.g. ["QUA", "UA", "L"] -> "QUAUAL"

This may output the same result multiple times. You can add the -1 flag to only output the first result.

Perl 5 + -pl, 18 bytes
1while s;(.+)\K\1;
Try it online!

Brachylog, 16 15 bytes
~c₃↺{h&~j}ʰ↻c↰|

Try it online!
Explanation
I wouldn't be surprised if there's a better way to do this.
~c₃↺{h&~j}ʰ↻c↰|
~c₃               "Unconcatenate" the input string into three substrings
   ↺              Rotate the first element to the end
    {    }ʰ       Apply this predicate to the new first element:
     h&             Assert that it is nonempty
       ~j           Assert that it consists of a substring repeated twice,
                    and return that substring
           ↻      Rotate the final element back to the beginning
             c    Concatenate the list back together
              ↰   Call the main predicate again on the result
               |  If there was no way to partition the input string that
                  satisfied the assertions, return the input unchanged


Wolfram Language (Mathematica), 31 29 bytes
f[a___,b__,b__,c___]=f[a,b,c]

Try it online!
Input [characters...]. Return the characters of the reduced string, wrapped in f.
NonCommutativeMultiply (**) is a conveniently Flat undefined operator. Unfortunately, it needs to be Unprotected before we can add a definition. Try it online!

Python 3.8 (pre-release), 82 bytes
lambda s:(n:=len(s))==[s:=s.replace((x:=s[i%n:i%~n])+x,x)for i in range(n**3)]or s

Try it online!
-14 bytes thanks to xnor

Fails for <oo><ooo>.

@Neil thanks, fixed!

Nice, I was going to try <ooq><oqq> next, but now I don't have to!

Cycling n times seems to work? There's maybe a better way to handle empty inputs.

Probably this suffices

@xnor nice one!

Setanta, 105 bytes
gniomh(s){le t idir(0,fad@s)le j idir(1,fad@s+1)le i idir(0,j){t=cuid@s(i,j)s=athchuir@s(t+t,t)}toradh s}

Try on try-setanta.ie

Retina 0.8.2, 11 bytes
+`(.+)\1
$1

Try it online! Link includes test cases. Explanation: Blatant rip-off of @Adám's rip-off of @l4m2's golf of @Arnauld's answer.

Charcoal, 30 bytes
Ｗ⌈ΦＥθ⌈ΦＥλ✂θμλ¹№θ×²μκ≔⪫⪪θ×²ιιθθ

Try it online! Link is to verbose version of code. Explanation:
Ｗ⌈ΦＥθ⌈ΦＥλ✂θμλ¹№θ×²μκ

While there are substrings of the input that appear doubled in the input, take the maximum, and...
≔⪫⪪θ×²ιιθ

... deduplicate that substring from the input.
θ

Output the finally reduced string.

sed 4.2.2, 16
:
s/(.+)\1/\1/
t


-1 byte thanks to @Neil .

Try it online!

Do you need the +?

@Neil - yes - thanks!
